# Reversing pagination results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have some data in my database as below

```
ID, Name, PriorityOrder
1 , AA,   1
2 , BB,   2
3 , CC,   3
4 , DD,   4
5 , EE,   5
6 , FF,   6
7 , GG,   7
8 , HH,   8
9 , II,   9
```

I have a grid using AngularJS (but i dont believe the issue is with that). The page displays with the usual pagination button i.e.

Prev 1,2 Next

At present i have limited the data to 5 items per page. You then have to press Next to view the next set of data.

The code to do this is

```
public PagedCategory GetCategories(int pageNumber, int skip = 0, int take = 0)
        {
            var pc= new PagedCategory();

            if (take > 0)
            {
                var q = ctx.GetSortedData();// sorted by PriorityOrder at the repository class
                pc.Categories = q.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
                pc.TotalItems = q.Count();
                pc.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
                var tp = Math.Ceiling((double)pc.TotalItems / take);
                pc.TotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(tp);
            }

            return pc;
        }
```

On page load the data is displayed in PriorityOrder (so it displays A-E) and clicking next shows the last set of data (F-I). So far it seems to be working. The above method in debug mode confirms the below values for each variable,

```
pageNumber = 1 
skip = 0 
take = 5.
```

Click Next and then

```
pageNumber = 2 
skip = 5 
take = 5
```

When i click **Prev** i can see

```
pageNumber = 1 
skip = 4 
take = 5
```

which displays the data **E-I** when im expecting **A-E**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's like your code has no issue, you should check the `Angular` code that sends the wrong `skip` value

Answer (score 0):

You are dependent on the value of `skip` which apparently doesn't get reset to 0  in your angular app. I would remove this dependency and only pass page size and page number to the back end.

An extension method like the below could help you with this;

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Page<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source, int pageSize, int currentPage)
{
    return source
        .Skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
        .Take(pageSize);
}
```

Use it like this;

```
var list =
    context
        .SomeData
        .Where(filterExpression)
        .OrderBy(sortExpression)
        .Page(paging.PageSize, paging.CurrentPage)
        .Select(projectionExpression)
        .ToList();
```